# Trying to convert each x'th character to Uppercase

Tags: python-3.x

So basically my homework consists of making a program that asks for a string and an integer 'x'.'x' is basically the step in this program. First it converts the whole string to lowercase and then each 'x'th' character of the string must be converted to uppercase. So if i input "Hello World" and my integer is 1. Output would be "hElLo wOrLd". Im new to python by the way.

This is what ive got right now and im basically stuck in a loop of trying a 100 things:

```
s = input('Input a string: ')
g = input('Input an integer: ')
s = s.lower()       #converts the whole string ofc
s = list(s)
range1 = s[::g]
range1 = range1.upper()
print(s)
```

Comment: wouldn't every 1st character mean all caps?

Answer (score 1):

First, convert `g` to an `int` because `input` returns a `str` and you can't slice a `list` with a `str`, also, `s[::g]` (which should be `s[g::g + 1]`) is an independent sublist of `s`, and it has no reference to `s`, so assigning it to `range1` and modifying it will not modify `s`, and one more note, `s[::g]` is a list, and you should call `str.upper` on its elements, not on it itself, you can use `map` for this:

```
s = list(input('Input a string: ').lower())
g = int(input('Input an integer: '))
s[g::g + 1] = map(str.upper, s[g::g + 1])
s = ''.join(s)
print(s)
```

Input:

```
Input a string: Hello World
Input an integer: 1
```

Output:

```
hElLo wOrLd
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Very quick answer.